# how to add bottom navigation bar in another fragment

Tags: android

I have already add an bottom navigation bar into my project with 3 fragments (Home_fragment, Wallet_fragment,Account_fragment). I have added login button in Account_fragment. Now i want that When ever i click on login button login_fragment(afterlogin_fragment) open with bottom navigation bar.

I have attaching a link to video showing my problem. link -- https://cloud.degoo.com/share/o41Axz4FYFHBx7

and here is codes ---

mainActivity ---

```
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, new HomeFragment()).commit();

    }



    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            Fragment selecrFlag = null;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    selecrFlag = new HomeFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_wallet:
                    selecrFlag = new WalletFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_Account:
                    selecrFlag = new AccountFragment();
                    break;


            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, selecrFlag).commit();
            return true;


        }


    };

};
```

Account_fragment ---

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
        EmailID = v.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        Passwd = v.findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        SignUpBt = v.findViewById(R.id.signbutton);
        LoginBt = v.findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

        LoginBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AccountFragment.this.getContext(),AfterLogin.class));
            }
        });
```

afterlogin Fragment --

```
package com.thechamp.earnbyads;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class AfterLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_login);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are confused. the way that you move to another Screen is not Fragment. It is Activity.
There are many ways to deal with this.

1. you can change your AfterLogin to Fragment.
2. or implement the AfterLogin Activity as what you implement in your Current Activity that has those 3 Fragments.

Comment: i want to add navigation bottom bar in AfterLogin activity please help me i am beginner